# Re-enabling touch screen on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, touchscreen

I work in a dispensary doing security. I'm on a computer that has no admin privileges I can use to restore the touch screen using Device Manager.  The card scanner I was using was right next to the lower left side of the keyboard and I managed to hit a key or keys that disabled the touch screen.  How do I re-enable the touch screen?  Windows 10 Lenovo.

Answer (score 0):

**Did you follow the [official tutorial](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028019/windows-enable-and-disable-your-touchscreen-in-windows-10)?**

It is not possible without admin privileges. Try to start your computer in [safe mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12376/windows-10-start-your-pc-in-safe-mode).

Enable and disable your touchscreen in Windows 10

1. In the search box on the taskbar, type **Device Manager**, then select
   **Device Manager**.
2. Select the arrow next to **Human Interface Devices** and select
   **HID-compliant touch screen**.
3. Select the **Action** tab at the top of the window. Select **disable** or  **enable**.

[image]